# Escape spaces in glob() in PHP?

Tags: php, glob

I have the following function in PHP, which is working great except for files with spaces in their names (`Good picture.jpg` for example).  Here it is:

```
function getphotolist($currentalbum) {
    $photos = glob($currentalbum.'/*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]');
    $albumparts = explode('_', $currentalbum);
    switch (array_key_exists(2,$albumparts)) {
        case false:
            usort($photos,"cmpexiftime");
            break;
        case true:
            usort($photos,"cmpexiftimer");
            break;
    }
    $photolist = "";
    foreach($photos as $photo){ 
        $phototitle = explode('_',basename($photo,".jpg"));
        $title = $phototitle[0];
        $thumb = $currentalbum.'/thumbs/'.basename($photo,".jpg").'_thumb.jpg';
        $exif = read_exif_data_raw("$photo",0);
        $desc = $exif["IFD0"]["ImageDescription"];
        $camera = ucwords(strtolower($exif["IFD0"]["Model"]));
        switch($exif["SubIFD"]["LensInfo"]) {
            case "105.0 mm f/2.8":
                $lens = "AF-S Micro-Nikkor 105mm &#402;/2.8 VR";
                break;
            case "50.0 mm f/1.8":
                if ($camera=="Nikon D700") {
                    $lens = "AF-S Nikkor 50mm &#402;/1.8 G";
                } else {
                    $lens = "AF Nikkor 50mm &#402;/1.8 D";
                }
                break;
            case "18.0-55.0 mm f/3.5-5.6":
                $lens = "AF-S Nikkor 18-55mm &#402;/3.5-5.6 II";
                break;
            default:
                $lens = $exif["SubIFD"]["LensInfo"];
                break;
        }
        $length = str_replace(" ","",$exif["SubIFD"]["FocalLength"]);
        $shutter = str_replace(" ","",str_replace("ec","",$exif["SubIFD"]["ShutterSpeedValue"]));
        $aperture = str_replace("f","&#402;",$exif["SubIFD"]["ApertureValue"]);
        $iso = $exif["SubIFD"]["ISOSpeedRatings"];
        list($width,$height) = getimagesize($photo);
        if ($height==1080 && $width==1920) {
            $photolist .= '<span data-title="'.$title.'" data-thumb="'.$thumb.'" data-desc="'.$desc.'" data-camera="'.$camera.'" data-lens="'.$lens.'" data-length="'.$length.'" data-shutter="'.$shutter.'" data-aperture="'.$aperture.'" data-iso="'.$iso.'" style="background-image:url('.$photo.'); background-size:cover;" class="slide"></span>';
        } elseif ($height >= $width) {                            
            $photolist .= '<span data-title="'.$title.'" data-thumb="'.$thumb.'" data-desc="'.$desc.'" data-camera="'.$camera.'" data-lens="'.$lens.'" data-length="'.$length.'" data-shutter="'.$shutter.'" data-aperture="'.$aperture.'" data-iso="'.$iso.'" style="background-image:url('.$photo.'); background-size:contain;" class="slide"></span>';
        } else {
            $photolist .= '<span data-title="'.$title.'" data-thumb="'.$thumb.'" data-desc="'.$desc.'" data-camera="'.$camera.'" data-lens="'.$lens.'" data-length="'.$length.'" data-shutter="'.$shutter.'" data-aperture="'.$aperture.'" data-iso="'.$iso.'" style="background-image:url('.$photo.'); background-size:contain;" class="slide"></span>';
        }
    }
return $photolist;
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this to work with files with spaces?  Thanks!

Comment: If you're asking how to fix something it's generally helpful to tell us how it's broken.

Comment: @Sammitch Sorry, basically what appears to happen is that it just doesn't pass the `$photo` variable along, so I end up with a `<span>` with everything but the `background-image` specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this code to escape space in filename when using glob:

```
$albumEscaped = str_replace(' ', '\ ', $currentalbum); 
$photos = glob($albumEscaped .'/*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]');
```

Comment: Used your answer in a little bit of a different way and solved the issue.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Space is not the only character that must be escaped when using glob().

Copied from [PHP docs comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#86425):

> I finally found the proper way to escape stuff in glob()
> If you want to add a directory path before your pattern, you should do
> it like this:
>
> ```
> <?php glob(preg_replace('/(\*|\?|\[)/', '[$1]', $dir_path).'*.txt');
> ?>
> ```
>
> preg_quote WILL NOT work in all cases (if any).